# How does the NNTP peering protocol works?

Tags: nntp

I can't find any doc online and i got lost on the RFC.

Could someone please explain me how does a NNTP server peering with another accept news?

I can only use my imagination:

```
 telnet nntp-server 119
 Trying nntp-server...
 Connected to nntp-server.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 200 nntp-server
 ihave <[message id?]>
 440 feeding not allowed
 [my imagination capabilities ends here]
```

I only want to receive news, not to send them.

Any tip? Many thanks.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3977#section-6.3.2

Comment: if you're doing Java, the GNU API is good.  You can examine the source to see how it actually works, perhaps that will help.

Comment: thanks, i solved by sniffing the traffic sent to me while doing a real peering ;)

Comment: glad to hear it.  Just to throw another NNTP tool out there, I like [leafnode](http://leafnode.sourceforge.net/).